# Output only styles that use certain variables?

Tags: sass

In SCSS, is there a way to output only styles that use certain variables?

I have color variables all in one file, but they are used all over the stylesheet. Now I want to add a different color theme without duplicating all the styles unrelated to color, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy (and quite error prone) to determine usage of certain variables for output. You could check if they are defined using `@if($x)` but that might not be what you're looking for.

But I don't think I fully understand what you're trying to achieve...

Is it:

1. white labeling your app/site (so 'overriding' the original values with new values)?
2. Having two separate 'themes' exist on their own (unique variables) but avoiding conflicts that might happen due to overlapping styles?

For:

1. Redefine the variables, given this line: `$x = 1; $x = 2; z-index:$x;` the z-index will be `2`. So something like: `@import 'base-theme'; @import 'client-theme'` would override every existing variable with the value from `client-theme` which would mean zero rewrites of existing styles (and only one extra  file with the new theme).
2. You will need to add logic for this, so rewriting styles will be a likely outcome. something like `@if($hotpink) { color:$hotpink } @else { color:$original-pink}` should work for those, but it will be cumbersome and quite hard to maintain.

My recommendation (for most use-cases): Go with option #1, it will save you a lot of work and debugging.

Hope that helps, feel free to ask if this seems unclear.

Comment: more like `.foo { border: 3px solid $color_border; padding: 10px; }` compiling to the main file and `@import 'colors-alt'; .foo { border: 3px solid $color_border; }` compiling to a separate file that just has styles that use variables overridden in `_colors-alt.scss`. I'm hoping for some way I don't need to split it into "color rules" and "everything else" sections. Worst case, I just output two full copies of the CSS, one with the color variables changed.